# Cassandra Datastax Driver - Guava - CodecRegistry.findCodec NullPointerException

Tags: cassandra, guava, datastax-java-driver

out of the blue, I started getting a NullPointerException with the Datastax driver for Cassandra, version 3.2

I really don't understand what is going on. The same query seems to work 99% of the times but every once in a while I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter value cannot be null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:228)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:524)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.maybeCreateCodec(CodecRegistry.java:642)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:550)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:532)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:407)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Utils.appendValue(Utils.java:98)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Assignment$SetAssignment.appendTo(Assignment.java:57)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Utils.joinAndAppend(Utils.java:44)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Update.buildQueryString(Update.java:73)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.BuiltStatement.toString(BuiltStatement.java:295)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.BuiltStatement$ForwardingStatement.toString(BuiltStatement.java:446)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Update$Where.toString(Update.java:227)
    at ....my code here
```

Do you have any idea of what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

guess your answer is in your question: Parameter value cannot be null